# Sublime Text 3 path snippet issue

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I just want to select 'folder*' and 'filename' to edit but I can't, below code does not work for me.
This file path with screenshot.

[image]

So I just try to write snippet code for 3 fields like below.

```
"\\\${1:folder1}\\\${2:folder2}\\\${3:filename}.jpg"
```

---

**Second issue** 
[image]

 I just try to write code for **'0'** (zero).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not fully clear what you're trying to accomplish, but per the unofficial documentation on snippets, the project name variable is not one of the ones that can be inserted using a snippet; you would have to define your own custom command to be able to do that. http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: I already read it, but I can't solve my issue, so I need to share screenshot and I hope it will help to shows my snippet issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want a snippet to complete to what's shown in the screenshot. In that case your “code” does not work because you're escaping the `$`, which makes your snippet useless.

> If you want to get a literal `$`, you have to escape it like this: `\$`.

Instead, you want to add another backslash to expand the snippet with two backslashes in place.

This following will expand with `\\` and tab-stops in place:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
"\\\\${1:folder1}\\\\${2:folder2}\\\\${3:filename}.jpg"
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Regarding your second issue: there are two ways to create tab-stops, with default values (e.g. `${1:default_value}` and without (e.g. `$1`). So, you should use `${1:0}` if you want it to contain `0` by default.

Comment: Thanks so much more, you just clearly understand me.

Comment: _( I do not want to write basic snippet code )_
`${1:function}($210, $3name, $4false){}`
I know I can write `${2:}10`
But I am just wondering if I need to make tab-stops in place before numeric symbol, how can I write good code for it.

Comment: I just added second issue in main Question.